# How to prevent super user deletion in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In django admin I have 4 users and a super user. I have Users with staff status that have limited access and cannot delete/view/edit users but the admin has authority over every other users and models. I do want the superuser to be able to access the users data and edit/modify/delete them but I do not want the superuser to be able to delete himself/herself. Currently the superuser can delete himself. Is there a way to disable the superuser delete by himself/herself in django?? Any help would be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: You could override the admin for your User model and raise an exception if you detect the superuser is trying to delete himself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

DO NOT USE has_delete_permission() override as it is not being called on every object when you perform delete action from changelist.

Use signals to do it. Add this to any models.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=User)
def delete_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_superuser:
        raise PermissionDenied
```

The only drawback of this method is that nobody will be able to delete any super user. You will have to set users attribute "is_superuser" to False before you can delete it.

Comment: yes thanks, it worked fine for me ....at the end it showed 403 forbidden if the superuser was trying to delete himself.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to override `UserAdmin` so that it won't allow deleting as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_delete_permission):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
       if obj is None:
           return True
       else:
           return not obj.is_superuser

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Comment: It seems that Django only calls this function to determine whether the "Delete" button is displayed or not. When you select the user from the list and remove many at once, the function is called with `obj=None`. You may either suppress deleting from the list by returning `False` when `obj=None` or hiding superusers overriding the `queryset` function (`get_queryset` in Django 1.6).

Comment: Yes this is what I meant ;)